# Creating a process tree with 4 children

Tags: c, unix, fork

I am having trouble creating this process tree.

[image: Process Tree]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    printf("\n [ID = %d] I am the root parent \n", getpid());
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        pid_t ret=fork();
        if(ret <0) //eror occured
        {       
            printf("Fork Failed \n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (ret == 0){
            printf("\n [ID =%d] My parent is [%d]\n", getpid(), getppid());
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my output

```
[ID = 4478] I am the root parent 

 [ID =4479] My parent is [4478]

 [ID =4480] My parent is [4479]

 [ID =4481] My parent is [4480]

 [ID =4482] My parent is [4481]
```

When I sketch this out, it's just a chain process tree.

```
p
|
C1
|
C2
|
C3
|
C4
```

I tried other methods of writing this but this was as close to getting four children. I've been getting 6 on my other tries.

Comment: Your root node should have two children only. Why do you create 4?

Comment: You should add some control to know which process is going to `fork()`, the root need to fork twice, the childs only once.

Comment: Is that an assigment?

Comment: The loop only run once for every process (except the last, where `i == 4` and it doesn't run at all), because you are stucking the loop in the parent process of the `fork` with the `wait` and `exit` calls. Also, you're not controlling which process is being forked.

Answer (score 2):

Your flaw is in the logic of the program itself. First you think of making a loop with 4 iterations, when in reality you only want 2 children on the parent process. But then, when `fork` is successful (`ret > 0`) you are calling `wait(NULL); exit(0);` which will stop the `for` loop and exit the process once `wait` stops hanging. When the children are `forked`, they will be inside the `for` loop themselfs as well. If the loop wasn't getting stuck in the `wait(NULL); exit(0);` statements you'd have an even bigger mess, with the parent process having 4 children, and the childrens having between 3 and 0 childrens, and the grandchildrens having between 2 and 0 childrens, and so on..

What you need is something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
  pid_t ret = fork();

  if(ret < 0){
    printf("Fork Failed!\n");
    return 1;
  } else if(ret == 0) { //Children process
    pid_t children_ret = fork();

    if(children_ret < 0){
      printf("Fork Failed!\n");
      return 1;
    } else if(children_ret == 0) { //Grandchildren process
      //... Do whatever you want on the grandchildren process
      exit(0);
    }

    //... Do whatever you want on the children process
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
  }
}
//... Do whatever you want on the parent process
wait(NULL);
exit(0);
```

Note that the `exit` calls on the children and grandchildren processes are **very important**. That's because all the processes share the same code, so if they don't exit on those points they will keep running whatever rest of code you have (i.e.: the grandchildren will run the children code and the parent code).

Comment: In the line where you have the grandchildren process comment, instead of it being "ret" is it suppose to be a "children_ret"? Since it's coming from the children. I think I'm starting to understand this now.

Comment: @Yvette — yes, there is a typo

Comment: @Yvette Exactly, it was a typo. I just edited the answer!